# Word 2010 Display current page of TotalPages while having multiple sections?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, page-numbers

Trying to set up a page numbering scheme in Word 2010. I have multiple sections on my document. Each section I have the page number counter "StartAt" set to 1. 
So in the footer of each page I can display something like "Page 1 of x from Section y"

What I need to do now is to also display to current page number inside the document. Using the NumPages field code I get the total number of pages of the document. How can I display the current page. The PAGE field code display the current page of the current section. Is there something else I could have missed?

Example:
Document with a total of 5 pages. Section 1 is page 1 and 2. Section 2 is pages 3,4,5.

Footer in the 2nd page of section 2 should look like this:

Page 2 of 3 from section 2 - Page 4 of 5 from document

I know how to get everything, except the "4" i.e. the page number inside the document not considering sections.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In really straightforward situations there is a slightly simpler way.

You make the page numbering continuous, then instead of the suggested { SEQ } fields, you put

```
{ SEQ p \r{ PAGE } \h }
```

at the beginning of each section.

Then for the per-section page numbering you use

```
{ ={ PAGE }-{ SEQ p \c }+1 }
```

All these schemes get harder to use if the sections you want to number are not identical to "Word sections." For example, if you need a landscape page in a portrait document, you have to insert a break just to achieve that, so what you want to think of as a single Section then becomes 2 or 3 Word sections and the field coding has to take account of that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working answer on this site:
[Insert two page numbering schemes in a word document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-two-page-numbering-schemes-in-a-word-document-HA001034900.aspx) (under the section 'The more technical method (automates the entire page-numbering process)')

It applies to Word 2002, but also works in 2010. Maybe there is however a simpler solution?

Comment: I think that in really straightforward situations there is a slightly simpler way. You make the page numbering continuous, then instead of the suggested { SEQ } fields, you put { SEQ p \r{ PAGE } \h } at the beginning of each section. Then for the per-section page numbering you use { ={ PAGE }-{ SEQ p \c }+1 }. All these schemes get harder to use if the sections you want to number are not identical to "Word sections" (e.g. if you need a landscape page in a portrait document, you have to insert a break to achieve that, but you might want the numbering to reflect a different structure).

Comment: Hey thanks. That did also the trick and is much mre straightforward as you said. At least, it's enough for my purposes

Comment: @bibadia: If you'd post your comment as an answer, I'd accept that as the accepted answer.